# How to compile SFML program with shader using g++

Tags: c++, sfml

I have simple sfml program(https://github.com/ArtemOnigiri/RealTimeRayTracing/commit/544f35bdfe6d0e0b8b85e7235c0488ac7de143b5#diff-ff9db3cb6025e343dacac7fe1b565394e85d2b614be4ab7b7fedb99d8e8b762d I copy it from github) that must create simple gradient that includes shader. My main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    int w = 1920;
    int h = 1080;
    sf::Clock clock;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(w, h), "Ray tracing", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    
    sf::RenderTexture emptyTexture;
    emptyTexture.create(w, h);
    sf::Sprite emptySprite = sf::Sprite(emptyTexture.getTexture());
    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("OutputShader.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.draw(emptySprite, &shader);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My OutputShader.fraq:

```
void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(uv, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I compile this with

```
g++ -Isrc/include -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

How to compile this right(maybe with cmake)?

Comment: What problem exactly are you encountering with your current setup?

Comment: As far as I know, the shader should be compiled when you call `loadFromFile()`, the documentation states that "The source must be a text file containing a valid shader in GLSL language." Looking at the source code for `loadFromFile()` it looks like it contains the code to compile the shader.

Comment: I copy code from https://github.com/ArtemOnigiri/RealTimeRayTracing/commit/544f35bdfe6d0e0b8b85e7235c0488ac7de143b5#diff-ff9db3cb6025e343dacac7fe1b565394e85d2b614be4ab7b7fedb99d8e8b762d

Comment: But when I start this window is not responding

Comment: Hmm, not sure what would cause the window to not respond, when I run it I see a gradient, black at the top left, red at the top right, green at the bottom left, yellow at the bottom right. I will see if compiling with the commandline will result in anything different.

Comment: Maybe because I have AMD Radeon

Comment: Not nvidia graphic card

Comment: Are you using the command the same as me to compile?

Comment: If no please type your command to compile

Comment: I use AMD Radeon as well, specifically an RX480. I am now using the commandline on Windows using Clang++, which seems to work. `clang++ -Iinclude -c main.cpp` and `clang++ main.o -o main.exe -Llib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system` were the commands I used. Do you have the dynamic libraries and the shader in the same directory as the executable? On windows its the `.dll` files, on linux I think they are called `.so`.

Comment: I install SFML from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljhpsdz8Ouo tutorial. But instead of Make file i created .bat file that execute g++ -Isrc/include -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

Comment: You need to poll events in your main loop, or the window will stay unresponsive. Even if you don't use them, there is underlying functionality done in the event polling that is required. This is covered in SFMLs documentation.

Comment: Yes dlls and shader are in same directory as executable

Comment: I said that I copied from https://github.com/ArtemOnigiri/RealTimeRayTracing/commit/544f35bdfe6d0e0b8b85e7235c0488ac7de143b5#diff-ff9db3cb6025e343dacac7fe1b565394e85d2b614be4ab7b7fedb99d8e8b762d but I don't show all code

Comment: I do not know what the issue is, last thing I can recommend is check you downloaded the right library. I personally have never used GCC, so I do not know what issues if could have.

Comment: Then include that in your question. Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. How can we know what's wrong if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: I don't mean to bust your balls, but you clearly didn't read the link I posted. The question should be self-contained, so the code should be copied into the question. Posting a link to the code is no good for several reasons.

Comment: One simple thing you can check is the return value from `loadFramFile`. It will return true if loading succeeded, false if it failed. Good things to exclude before checking anything else.

Comment: I add full code to the post